# Using if statment to compare variable in User Profile

Tags: user-profile, display-template

I've created a display template based off the Item_Person template in the SharePoint 2013 on Premises application. This template list the Departments, Branch Location and Regions. On the display template they are shown like the example below.

```
_#= displayName =#_
_#= displayJtitle =#_ 
_#= displayDept =#_  (Department)
_#= displayol =#_    (Branch Location)
_#= displayreg =#_   (Region)
```

I have two questions but they are similar.

I am looking to only show Regions for employees who's User Profile field *Region* does not show "Non Region", so for a corporate employee they will not have a Region, but a Branch Employee will have a region. In our HR System, there were unable to leave this field blank so they chose to just put in "Non Region" for corporate employees. How can I filter out a User that does not have a region and not display that area.

```
<!--#_
  var encodedreg = $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.Region)
  var displayreg = Srch.U.getSingleHHXMLNodeValue(hhProps, "Region")
  if ($isEmptyString(displayreg)) { displayreg = encodedreg }
 _#-->
  <!--#_ if(encodedreg != "Non Region") {   _#-->
    <div id='region'>Region: </span> _#= displayreg =#_ </div>
  <!--#_ } _#-->
```

Next, we have one Branch that has a Mailing Address that is not it's Physical Address. Is there a way I can look for the Branch Name and only show the Mailing Address if its that particular branch?

```
<!--#_
  var encodedol = $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.OfficeLocation)
  var displayol = Srch.U.getSingleHHXMLNodeValue(hhProps, "OfficeLocation") 
  if ($isEmptyString(displayol)) { displayol = encodedol }
_#-->
   <!--#_if(encodedol == "Branch Main") {    _#--> 
    <div id='MailAdd'>Mailing Address: </span>P.O. Box ####</div>
  <!--#_ } _#-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945138(v=office.15).aspx). You can see conditional statements are written as

```
<!--#_
if(!linkURL.isEmpty)
{
_#-->
     <a class="cbs-pictureImgLink" href="_#= linkURL =#_" title="_#= $htmlEncode(line1.defaultValueRenderer(line1)) =#_" id="_#= pictureLinkId =#_">
<!--#_
}
_#-->
```

Try this

```
<!--#_
if(!encodedol.isEmpty && encodedol.indexOf('Branch Main') >= 0)
{
_#-->
     <div id='MailAdd'>Mailing Address:</div>
<!--#_
}
_#-->
```

Comment: How can I do this with a specific variable, so not looking to see if its empty but to see if the branch name is "Branch Main" @Amal Hashim

Comment: @Alvina I have updated my answer

Comment: OMG Yes it worked. Thank you so much. So the Index of looks at specific variables?

Comment: @Alvina indexof will basically look the entire string. so if the string has leading or trailing spaces it works fine.